# What is the difference between 2 constructors?

Tags: java, memory, constructor

I have a constructor that gets objects as function parameters. I have 2 ways to write it, but I want to make sure I understand the difference between both ways. I also want to know which way is better:

```
public class Line {
    private Point start;
    private Point end;
/**
 * First method: copy the data from each point with get functions
 */
public Line(Point start, Point end) {
    this.start = new Point(start.getX(), start.getY());
    this.end = new Point(end.getX(), end.getY());
}
/**
 * Second method: equal the class variables to the parameters from the function
 */
public Line(Point start, Point end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

From what I understand, in the first method, I allocate a memory for each point and copy the data from the objects.

In the second method, I point to the memory of existing objects, and so, if I use this constructor, and in another function I change the objects, the change will also appear in the line.

I think that the first method is better and safer, but I was wondering if that's true.
Thanks!

Comment: In general, your assumption is correct. If someone passes a point to the `Line` constructor, and then changes the x or y value of it, then the state of the `Line` instance will change too! That is often undesired behaviour. That's why immutability gets more important these days.

Comment: As you've explained, they do different things. If the behavior you need is the second, then use the second. If not, use the other one.

Comment: The first does a (shallow) copy of the Point objects while the second doesn't and just sets the fields to reference the passed objects. So if you where to modify one of the Point objects after you called your Line constructors with them, then that modification would have no effect on the Line object if you used the first constructor, but it would also modify the Line object if you used the second constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, you've been very helpful!!